# <Dial><Number> TwiML not dialling a phone number

Tags: php, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

Hi I'm trying to write some TwiML XML code to dial a number. This is my code at the moment:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: text/xml');
   $callerID = "XXXTWILIONUMBERXXX";
?>
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="<?php echo $callerId ?>">
      <Number>XXXNUMBERTOCALLXXX</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem is that when I'm testing it using the TwiML app creation page (where the app SID is found) it hits the TwiML okay but then doesn't dial the number.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please use a plus sign (like +982348872364) in the caller id. Make sure your twiml should be accessible by twilio means your twiml should be on a public url that can be accessed any where from the world.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's still not calling the number in the <Number></Number> tag

Comment: is your twiml on a public url?